# Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a simple table that collects data from json and displays the info in the table.

In the table I also have a highlighted background for people with over 100 score. And a button to change their colours.

I have wrapped the colour changing as a context provider.

When my table renders I get this error message in console.

```
react-dom.development.js:51 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Table. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useState                   useState
3. useState                   useState
4. useState                   useState
5. useEffect                  useEffect
6. undefined                  useContext
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at Table (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:447:71)
    at ColorContextProvider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:207:5)
    at App
```

Below is the code:

```js
import CheckScore from "./checkScore";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useColorContext } from "./contexts/Color";

export const Table = () => {
  const { setHighlightingColor } = useColorContext();

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [total2, setTotal2] = useState(0);
  const [average2, setAverage2] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("../players.json")
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((parsedData) => {
        const totalPoints = parsedData
          .map((player) => {
            return player.points;
          })
          .reduce((prevValue, curValue) => {
            return prevValue + curValue;
          });
        setUsers(parsedData);
        setTotal2(totalPoints);
        const averagePoints = total2 / parsedData.length;
        setAverage2(averagePoints);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App-header">
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setHighlightingColor("red")}>Red</button>
          <button onClick={() => setHighlightingColor("blue")}>Blue</button>
        </div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Points</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((e) => CheckScore(e.points, e.username))}
            <tr>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td>{total2}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Average</td>
              <td>{average2}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

And the checkScore code

```js
import { ColorContext } from "./contexts/Color";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function CheckScore(score, player) {
  const { highlightingColor } = useContext(ColorContext);

  return (
    <tr key={player} className={`${score > 100 ? highlightingColor : ""} `}>
      <td>{player}</td>
      <td>{score}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

And ColorContext

```js
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const ColorContext = createContext("red");

export const ColorContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [highlightingColor, setHighlightingColor] = useState("red");

  return (
    <ColorContext.Provider value={{ highlightingColor, setHighlightingColor }}>
      {children}
    </ColorContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useColorContext = () => useContext(ColorContext);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Need to see source code of `useColorContext`

Comment: I have now also included useColorCOntext source code

Comment: I updated my answer. If it helps, please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The problem is that you call `useContext` in `CheckScore` function.

Either way will fix:

1. Pass `highlightingColor` as param into `CheckScore` functiona, and don’t call `useContext` in it.
2. `{users.map((e) => <CheckScore score={e.points} player={e.username} />)}` and change params of `function CheckScore(score, player)` to `function CheckScore({ score, player })`

**Explanation**

You need to make clear distinction between a) “react functional component” and b) “a function that returns react elements”.

`CheckScore` is qualified as a functional component only when called as `<CheckScore />`. The way you called it, as a normal function, disqualify it from being a component, and so that `useContext` call is considered called within the lifespan of `<Table />` component.

When `users` count varies, count of `useContext` calls varies. As suggested in https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks, this code will cause trouble.

===

Below is a bug I spot in your code. Not related to your current question but worth noting. Here’s how to fix it. I post as answer because I can’t get proper format in comment.

```
    setTotal2(totalPoints);
    - const averagePoints = total2 / parsedData.length;
    + const averagePoints = totalPoints / parsedData.length;
    setAverage2(averagePoints);
```

At the point you calculate `averagePoints`, `total2 != totalPoints`. You should use `totalPoints` instead. Reason being that `setState` update is async, so `total2` is not updated until **next** render.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You saved me a lot of future headaches! :D

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Never knew about the part where FuncComponent() called in another component is not having it's own "context" unless called as <FuncComponent />